# Traceroute to check number of hops between my laptop and google.com

Tags: linux, ubuntu, traceroute

I am new to Linux and trying to learn traceroute command in ubuntu terminal. I entered ping command in my terminal to google.com and the results are:

```
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.194.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=10.8 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=11.4 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from del12s05-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.194.142): icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=11.9 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.800/11.862/12.926/0.631 ms
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$
```

But When I traceroute to google.com it is showing below output:

```
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.194.142), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.2.2  0.284ms  0.299ms  0.270ms 
  2   *  *  * 
  3   *  *  * 
  4   *  *  * 
  5   *  *  * 
  6   *  *  * 
  7   *  *  * 
  8   *  *  * 
  9   *  *  * 
 10   *  *  * 
 11   *  *  * 
 12   *  *  * 
 13   *  * ^C
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$
```

I have no idea why it is not showing me IP addresses of the hops. Please help me here.

Comment: Linux defaults to using UDP, what happens if you try ICMP `traceroute -I google.com`?

Comment: You should read the manual page: "If there is no response within a certain timeout, an "*" (asterisk) is printed for that probe." Note that there is no obligation for a router to reply.

Comment: It is ranking of various agencies. Unmasked the asterisks are things like `C I A`, `F S B`, `M I 6` `C C P` etc. (OK. That was a joke ... heh).

Comment: Thanks @PaulBurrows, for "traceroute -I google.com", it worked and showing all the hops IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "traceroute -I google.com" and it worked.

```
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$ traceroute -I google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.193.206), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.2.2  0.421ms  0.212ms  0.192ms 
  2   192.168.1.1  1.871ms  4.654ms  1.739ms 
  3   117.212.40.1  13.236ms  10.626ms  9.502ms 
  4   117.212.40.1  10.222ms  11.393ms  8.989ms 
  5   218.248.107.38  31.941ms  21.067ms  18.296ms 
  6   117.216.207.203  15.960ms  15.869ms  * 
  7   142.250.160.182  16.680ms  16.075ms  17.754ms 
  8   172.253.68.7  18.031ms  17.957ms  18.856ms 
  9   142.251.54.97  18.216ms  16.466ms  17.305ms 
 10   142.250.193.206  18.071ms  15.997ms  16.900ms 
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$
```

traceroute -I, --icmp: It is specified to use ICMP ECHO as a probe.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lft` ("The Layer Four Traceroute, which performs a TCP traceroute, like traceroute -T")

Example:-

```
sudo lft google.com  
Tracing .........**T
TTL LFT trace to lhr25s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.14):80/tcp
 1  router (192.168.1.1) 0.5ms
**  [neglected] no reply packets received from TTLs 2 through 3
 4  132.hiper04.sheff.dial.plus.net.uk (195.166.143.132) 5.7ms
 5  peer7-et-0-0-4.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.252.156) 10.3ms
 6  109.159.253.185 6.3ms
 7  72.14.232.76 7.7ms
 8  209.85.241.95 7.1ms
 9  [target open] lhr25s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.14):80 6.0ms
```